# Safe to have fluoride in water-system for cavity prevention? Bleach/whiten teeth after or before fluoride treatments?

Tags: oral-health, cavity, fluoride, bleach-teeth-whitening, toothpaste

I grew up in California. As such, I fortunately, have very healthy teeth. I didn't get my first cavity until I was 23 and living in the UK! haha. **So is having fluoride in your water-systems a healthy thing since it prevents cavities?** *Or does it cause a ton of other problems that I'm not aware of....*

I suppose instead of the free fluoride in the water, you can always pay for fluoride treatments at your dentist. **Is it better to bleach-whiten your teeth before or after the fluoride treatment? Why or why not?**